# Difficulty to understand a chain of equalities

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, classical-electrodynamics, gauge-invariance, gauge

If we start with a functional or integral action

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{F}(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}})=\iiiint_{D} L\Biggl(x_\nu, \mathcal{A}_\mu, \frac{\partial \mathcal{A}_\mu}{\partial x_\nu}\Biggr)d^4X
\end{equation}
with $\nu,\mu=1,\dotsb,4$ with $X=({x}_1,{x}_2,x_3,x_4)=(x,y,z,ict)$, where $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}=\Bigl(\vec{A}, \dfrac{i \varphi}{c}\Bigr)$, where $L$ is the Lagrangian density. Being

$$L'=L+\mu_{0}\square (f\boldsymbol{\mathcal{J}})$$ ($\square$ is 4-divergence operator) with $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{J}}$ the 4-vector density of current. If we define as a set of admissible functions that of the functions that assume the same value at the edge (no longer in the two extremes as for functions of a variable), why

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\iiiint_{D}L'\,d^{4}{X}&=\iiiint_{D}L\,d^{4}{X}+\mu_0\iiiint_{D}\square (f\boldsymbol{\mathcal{J}})d^{4}{X}=\\
&\stackrel{\color{red}{\bf ?}}{=}\mathscr{F}+\mu_{0}\int_{\partial D}(f\boldsymbol{\mathcal{J}})\cdot \hat n\, d^{4}{X}\stackrel{\color{red}{\bf ?}}{=}0, 
\end{aligned}\tag{?}
\end{equation}

where $D$ is particular domain.

NB: If that's helpful, I'm putting in a picture of a student's notes.

[image]

Comment: The first questionable integral is just the 4d version of the divergence (Gauss) theorem. The second questionable integral is due to the boundary conditions; presumably zero current density at the boundary. EDIT: No, the would give $\scriptF$ as the result. I don't know why you get zero.

Comment: How do you get a scalar from applying the D'Alembert operator to a vector?

Comment: @PhysicsTeacher I agree, but it should be $\partial_\mu(f J^\mu)$ rather than $\square$ - i.e. a divergence, not D'Alembert

Comment: @fqq you're right, I officially don't understand the integrations.

Comment: @PhysicsTeacher I edited the question by adding a snapshot of a student's notes. Thank you very much for your interesting.

Comment: @fqq Thank you very much for your interesting. See the edit and the previous comment.

Comment: so as I suspected $\square$ is not the D'Alembert operator but a divergence - a very misleading notation

Comment: Also from the last sentence in the notes it's clear that it should be $F'=F$, not zero

Comment: @fqq You have right. $\square$ is the 4-divergence. Sorry.

Comment: What does $f$ represent?

Comment: The first questionable equality is correct; the second is incorrect. The student’s notes are simply wrong. The conclusion is supposed to be $\mathscr{F}’=\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: What is the point of the weird notation $\mathcal{X}_1$, etc. instead of the standard $x_1$ ?

Comment: @G.Smith $f\in\mathcal C^2$; what is that the first correct and the second incorrect? I have changhed the notation. Thank you always very much.

Comment: There's no need to write four integral signs for a 4D integral... that just wastes ink and hurts the eyes.

Comment: @knzhou I have copied from the notes of a student in MathJaX. Sorry.

Comment: @Sebastiano The first equality holds because of the definition of $\mathscr{F}$ and the divergence theorem. The second term vanishes because $f$ vanishes on the boundary. The first term, $\mathscr{F}$, does not vanish, so the second equality is wrong.

Comment: @G.Smith With lot of cordiality can you add a detailed answer referring to the your comment, please?. I kindly ask you for the details because you cancel the outline etc.. These are topics I did 25 years ago. Thank you very much.